# How to deal uniformly with a factory returning unique_ptr and a getter returning a reference to global object?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Assume there is a global `Foo` object,

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int i;
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "gone: " << i << std::endl; }
};

Foo globalFoo{7};
```

that it can be retrieved via a function that returns it by reference,

```cpp
Foo& getFoo() {
    return globalFoo;
}
```

and that there's also a factory function to make a different `Foo` out of thin air,

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Foo> makeFoo() {
    return std::make_unique<Foo>(5);
}
```

The above is unchangeable.

In client code, whether one should use `makeFoo` or `getFoo` is determined by a runtime `bool`.

```cpp
int main()
{
    bool b{false};

    std::cin >> b;

    /* type */ foo = b
                   ? /* via getFoo */
                   : /* via makeFoo */;
}
```

What is the appropriate way to deal with this scenario?

I can tell that this is not the way:

```cpp
    auto& foo = b
              ? getFoo()
              : *makeFoo();
```

because `foo` is a dangling reference right after its created, [as the temporary result of `makeFoo()`, the `unique_ptr` will be destoryed](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xzzP3q8hM), thus taking the managed `Foo` with it.

This too is not the way:

```cpp
    auto& foo = b
              ? getFoo()
              : *makeFoo().release();
```

[because the object `*makeFoo().release()` is leaked](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5E8dMncP1), unless [I manually `delete` it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x5TsKnfd3).

Comment: Can the object be copied? Or do you need to work with a reference to the original object (in the case of the global variable)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, the reference to the global variable should be used, without copying the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the result in `shared_ptr` with a deleter that does nothing in case this is a global object. Unlike for `unique_ptr`, deleter of `shared_ptr` is not a part of the type of the smart pointer itself, so the type will be the same for both cases.

Something like this:

```
auto foo = b ? std::shared_ptr(&/* via getFoo */, [](Foo*){})
             : std::shared_ptr(/* via makeFoo */);
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `getFoo()` you does not own the object, but for `makeFoo()` you own it.

So you could store them in two types.

But you could make a reference to it:

```cpp
unique_ptr<Foo> ufoo;
Foo* ref{};
if(b) {
  ufoo = makeFoo();
  ref = ufoo.get();
} else {
  ref = &getFoo();
}
```

Then take `ref` for further use